# Windows not running any exe

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have Windows 7 Professional 64 bit on my machine.

I am doing all development activities under a a non-admin account.

From the past few days, whenever I try to run an executable as an Administrator, I get this error:

> Windows cannot find [Path to exe]. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

This occurs even when the exe is present in the location. At first, I thought the shortcuts had a problem, but even when I go into the actual folder where the exe is present and run it as Administrator, this is happening.

Googling didn't bring up many helpful links. There was one which asked to modify some registry keys, which I did, but no luck.

IIS, Visual Studio, The Command Prompt - I'm unable to run any of these (or any other exe) as Administrator.

I'm running a full virus scan as I type this, but in case anyone else has been unlucky enough to have encountered this, please help.

Comment: have you performed a disk check? is your system %PATH% valid?

Comment: %PATH% is valid. Haven't performed a disk check. Will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no virus, the admin account cannot run the exes because it does not have read/execute access to them, including the path they are on, therefore the 'path no found' error.

Make sure **interactive** user is present in the users group.

```
net localgroup Users
```

Groups can be seen with

`net localgroup`

Add the admin user to that group that contains the interactive user by using

```
net localgroup Users adminname* /add
```

where adminname* is your user account that you try to run the .exes under.